# Integration of an equation in terms of differential forms

Tags: differential-forms

Suppose we have the equation in terms of differential forms

$$ d\mathcal{Y}=f(C)dC,$$
here $d\mathcal{Y}(x^i)$ is one form, $C(x^i)$ is a scalar, $f(C)$ is a function of $C$ only.

Can it be integrated? Is the most general solution given by
$$ \mathcal{Y}=g(C)$$
with some arbitrary function $g(C)$.

I feel like it can be done and simply substituting $\mathcal{Y}=g(C)$ back into the equation we get
$$ d\mathcal{Y}=\partial_C g(C) dC,$$
so $\partial_C g(C)=f(C)$. Does it make sense?

Comment: Could you give more context?

Comment: I added some info in the question. Basically I want to find a solution of the given equation. For example, the answer "$\mathcal{Y}$ is a function on $C$ only" is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

We can look at the equation $d\mathcal{Y}=f(C)dC$ as the definition of the exact differential. Then obviously $\mathcal{Y}$ depends only on $C$, so the solution is $\mathcal{Y}=g(C)$.